# MongoDB isn't saving the dbpath that I assign to it. How can I save the dbpath?

Tags: mongodb, command-line-interface

Im setting my dbpath like so:

```
mongod --dbpath /Users/dylan/development/mongodb/data/db
```

it then connects to the db and runs fine. But as soon as I exit and try to start mongod again it comes up with this error:

```
Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option
```

for some reason it isn't saving the --dbpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a best practice to store all startup parameters in the  mongod.conf yaml file
and start the mongod process every time with mongo --config mongodb.conf file or as a service.
example content:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /Users/dylan/development/mongodb/data/db
```

If you dont specify the dbPath location , the mongod process start with default dbPath location( /data/db ) or if started as service the dbPath found in default config file located in linux  at /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.   The way you are starting mongod is stateless and you will need to use all parameters every time you start the service.   With that being said, if you start mongod while in the `/Users/dylan/development/mongodb` directory you wouldnt have to set dbpath.

Comment: I can do that. Why is it better to start with a --config flag and file rather than uisng the  --dpbath flag every time I start the service? currently I have an alias on my .zshrc for now that uses the --dbpath flag, I can easily set it to use the --config flag but what is the difference between the two?

Comment: simply in the config file you can add alot more settings that you would like on startup , but afcourse you can add those settings as command line arguments it is just easier to store everything in a file ...